# Safe to drive ~800km with diesel particulate filter warning?

Tags: obd-ii, diesel, mini-cooper, diesel-particulate-filter

My 2009 Mini Cooper D (R56) reads "Service" on the small dashboard display, and has the following fault codes (with their meanings that I looked up):

- P14A5 - Exhaust gas temperature sensor short to ground
- P14A6 - Diesel Particulate Filter System Flow Resistance Too Low
- 4199 - "exhaust temp sensor"?
- 4A27 - Intelligent Battery Sensor
- 41D4 - Particulate Filter regeneration maximum
- 4159 - Glowing system
- 4A07 - "Generator (later BSD)"

I tried inspecting the exhaust gas temperature sensor connector, but I can't find information online as to exactly which one this is, reconnecting everything I could see did not fix the issue.

I've tried taking it to a local garage but I was charged a large amount only to be told they don't have the correct tools to even diagnose the issue, and nearly every other nearby garage is booked out for weeks. I have a garage that my parents have used for years and have a lot of trust with, and I would be visiting for Christmas anyway.

Is it safe to use this car to make the 800KM trip? Are there any repairs I can attempt myself to make it safer/more reliable?